# Find point along line a specified distance from a polygon

Tags: python, numpy, geometry

Given a 2-D closed polygon defined by a series of points and an infinite line, I would like to find points on that line a specified distance from the polygon.  The polygon is known to be closed, not intersecting, and not containing 3 consecutive collinear points.  In general there are many possible points along the line.  Ideally I would like to find them all, or alternatively the one nearest some initial guess location.  I am using python but a solution in any language would be helpful.  I believe scipy.spatial [kdtree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query) will be one important component, but I cannot see how to do the whole solution.  Here is some code to define the problem, which shows at least some of the corner cases involved:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

poly = np.array([[0, 0],
                 [10, 0],
                 [10, 3],
                 [1, 1],
                 [1, 6],
                 [0, 6],
                 [.8, 4],
                 [0, 0]])

line = np.array([[-2, 4.5],
                 [12, 3]])

plt.plot(poly[:, 0], poly[:, 1])
plt.plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1])
plt.xlim([-1, 11])
plt.ylim([-1, 7])
plt.show()

points = find_points_distance_from_polygon(poly, line, distance)
```

[image]

Edit: I am looking for the algorithm to find the points.

Update:
What I have tried so far is an approximate solution using the distance to each point.  My thought was that if I refined the polygon by adding additional points along each line, then this approach might be accurate enough.  However I would have to add a lot of points if the distance was small.  I thought there is probably a better way.

```
import scipy.spatial as spatial
import scipy.optimize as opt
import math

def find_point_distance_from_polygon_along_line(tree, line, dist, guess_ratio):
    def f(x):
        pt = line[0, :] + x * (line[1, :] - line[0, :])
        d, i = tree.query(pt)
        return math.fabs(d - dist)

    res = opt.minimize(f, [guess_ratio])
    return line[0, :] + res.x * (line[1, :] - line[0, :])

tree = spatial.cKDTree(poly)
pt = find_point_distance_from_polygon_along_line(tree, line, 1, 0)
```

For the example in the plot and a distance of 0.5, I expect to find 4 points at approximately (.1, 4.2), (1.5, 4.1), (9.1, 3.3), and (10.5, 3.1).  My current plan would find more points, particularly points which are some distance from the opposite edge of the polygon.  I want the line connecting the point on the line to the polygon to be external to the polygon.

Comment: Your code basically just does the plotting. Are you asking for an *algorithm* to find the respective points?

Comment: Just look at http://pyimagesearch.com. You'll find whatever you're looking for.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes I am looking for the algorithm.  I edited the question to hopefully make that more clear

Comment: Well, what did you actually try so far? It's not exactly rocket science, so why not use a common intersection approach?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I added what I have done so far

Comment: Could you show at your picture what points at the line you consider as having distance 1 (or 0.5) from polygon?

Answer (score 0):

If number of polygon edges is reasonable, you can use simple linear algorithm.

Let's parametric equation for line is

```
L(u) = L0 + u * dL
```

where L0 is some base point, dL is direction vector, u is parameter

and parametric equation for i-th segment is

```
P = P[i] + t * Dir[i]
```

where P[i] is the first point of segment, Dir[i] is normalized direction vector, t is parameter in range 0..1

Arbitrary point at the line has it's projection on given segment at parameter

```
t = DotProduct(L(u) - P[i], Dir[i])    //equation 1
```

and length of normal to the projection (needed distance) is

```
Dist = Abs(CrossProduct(L(u) - P[i], Dir[i]))
Abs((L0x + u * dLx - Px) * Diry - (L0y + u * dLy - Py) * Dirx) = Dist 
so
u  = (+-Dist - ((L0x- Px)*Diry -(L0y-Py)*Dirx)) / (dLx * Diry - dLy * Dirx)
```

substitute values u into equation 1 and check if parameter t is in range 0..1 (projection inside the segment). If yes, L(u) is needed point.

Then check distance to vertices  - solve

```
(L0x + u * dLx - Px)^2 + (L0y + u * dLy - Py)^2 = Dist^2
```